# C program displays incorrect result

Tags: c, math

I have written a program which calculates the amount of money you need to pay. The user enters their principal amount, interest rate and time period in years and then the program gives them the amount they will have to pay in future. When I run the program the final result or the amount I need to pay is too big or incorrect. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int calculation_1(int principal, int rate, int years);

int main(void) {

    int amount1, amount3;
    double amount2, total;

    printf("Investement Calculator \n");
    printf("====================== \n");

    printf("Principal : ");
    scanf("%d", &amount1);

    printf("Annual Rate: ");
    scanf("%lf", &amount2);

    printf("No of Years: ");
    scanf("%d", &amount3);

    total = calculation_1(amount1, amount2, amount3);

    printf("The future value is: $%.2f \n", total);

    return 0;
}

int calculation_1(int principal, int rate, int years) {

    double subtotal,final;

    subtotal = principal * (1 + rate) * years;

    return subtotal;
}
```

I tested with these values: 1000 for principal, 0.06 for rate and 5 years for no of years. Final result should be $1338.23, but I get $5000.00. Here is the formula I used to calculate the amount:

```
total = principal * (1 + rate) ^number of years.
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You are multiplying by the number of years, not raising to the power of years. Use a pow() function.

Comment: Also `rate` should be `double`, not `int`.

Comment: @alk: heh - well spotted - offending "not" removed now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formula doesn't specify it correctly:

```
subtotal = principal * (1 + rate) * years;
```

should be

```
subtotal = principal * pow((1 + rate),years);
```

also look at the other answer (@ameycu).. your data type has a mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

```
int calculation_1(int principal, int rate, int years) //change 2nd parameter type to double
```

Function require 2 parameter as type `int` and you pass it a `double` while calling in `main`-

```
total = calculation_1(amount1, amount2, amount3);
   /*  amount2 is declared as double */
```

So , due to this fraction part in `amount2` will be discarded , which can lead to wrong answer.

And you need to use function [`pow`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_pow.htm) to use in formula, to get this expression in your mathematical formula :

[image]

Comment: Using `^` in the context of C to express the *power-of* operation is at least ambiguous.

Comment: @alk  Well , yes it just a mathematical formula . What he tried do to in program is something wrong for the logic .

Comment: In C `^` is the XOR-operator. Not everybody might parse it as *power-of*.

Comment: @alk  It really looks better . Thanks !!

Comment: No only just "*looks better*", which would not really matter, more important it's UNambiguous, clear, easy to understand, "fail-safe"! :-)

Comment: @alk  Totally agreed :)